# CommandArgument takes in only one character

Tags: vb.net

This is the link button code:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" OnCommand="red_pro" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("profile_id") %>'>
```

This is the code-behind:

```
Sub red_pro(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
        Dim commandArgsAccept As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()
        Dim value1 As String = commandArgsAccept(0).ToString
        Session("prosess") = value1
        Response.Redirect("XsProfile.aspx?id=" & value1)
    End Sub
```

The value stored in session is only one character long.
I need to store the complete data of the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have

`commandArgsAccept(0). ToString ()`

The zero in brackets means you want to select the first element of the string which is one character.  If you want the whole string,  just delete the brackets and the zero.

Comment: Hey thanks! That worked. :D Apparently, I was only removing the 0.